# How to update WordPress \ install new plugin(for WP) in ubuntu instance

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using WP+Ngnix+ubuntu as my aws instance(DEV,STG and PROD) and running with 4 sites. I need to install/add a new plugin and we need to do wordpress update (from 4.7 to 4.8). So, what are the things do i need to follow while this up-gradation? whether it will need downtime in live instance implementation ?
t2.micro - for DEV and STG
t2.large - for PROD

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this via admin console of the Wordpress. it doesn't take much time and you shouldn't worry about downtime.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snlxL.png)

Backup your database, and Wordpress code just for being safe!

Comment: Thanks @vineeth , no further action need from instance side ? like adding new plugin URL in "wp-content/Plugin " directory by SSH (putty) . If so please advise.

Comment: Not typically. You can add plugins directly from the console, thats my knowledge. Do try it out :)